# if $X$ is a compact metric space and $f: X \rightarrow X$ a contractive application then there exists a single point $x\in X$ such that $f (x) = x$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Prove the following result known as the contractive application theorem: if $X$ is a compact metric space and $f: X \rightarrow  X$ a contractive application (that is, there exists $K <1$ such that $d (f (x), f (y)) <Kd (x, y)$ for all $x \in X$ ) then there exists a single point $x\in X$ such that $f (x) = x$. (hint: if $a \in X$, consider the sequence $x_1 = a, x_n = f (x_ {n-1})$).

I have seen similar results, but with the difference that in the statement they speak of completeness not compactness. And I can't understand or demonstrate how to go from completeness to compactness. The idea that I use for the test is the following: If I can go from compact to complete, it would be enough for me to try cauchy, that would imply convergence and with the continuity of the function $f$ I obtain the fixed point. Uniqueness is much calmer.

The question is, how to go from compactness to completeness? ... And if this is not possible, how else could this statement prove.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please share your own efforts.

Comment: the idea is very similar to the fixed point theorem, you can check this https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Let us know what you've tried so far!

Using the hint, we have for example that $d(x_1,x_2)=d(f(x_0),f(x_1))\leq Kd(x_0,x_1).$

Similarly, using the triangle inequality we have for example that $$d(x_1,x_3)\leq d(x_1,x_2)+d(x_2,x_3)\leq[K+K^2]\cdot d(x_0,x_1).\hspace{0.5cm}{\text{(Why?)}}$$

What can you say in general, then, about $d(x_n,x_m)$? (HINT: create a Cauchy sequence, which you know will converge by the completeness of $X.$)

Comment: I think I can understand the idea: by continuing to iterate I will get a convergent series and to prove that this sequence is Cauchy and by completeness I get convergence, and then by the continuity of f (which I must prove) I get the fixed point and the uniqueness is much calmer. But I am new to compactness and I cannot connect or how to get from compact spaces to complete spaces.

Comment: @FionaEverdeen you need that compact metric spaces are complete, if you follow this proof. You don’t need to, though.

Comment: Sorry, what is not necessary?

Comment: @FionaEverdeen you could try another approach too, I mean. Continuity of $f$ is trivial from being a contractive map: we use $\delta=\varepsilon$ uniformly.. And if a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence the whole sequence is convergent, and this almost immediately gives that compact metric spaces are complete.